# When a run .fullcalendar({ options }) using scheduler, I get view glitches that get fixed on resource resize. Any idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar-scheduler inside a VueComponent, running the following code on component mounted.

```
        const scheduler = $('#scheduler');
        scheduler.fullCalendar('destroy');
        scheduler.fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'timeLine3Months,timelineYear'
          },
          visibleRange: {
            start: moment(new Date()).startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end: moment(new Date()).endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
          },
          displayEventTime: false,
          locale: 'it',
          height: 600,
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
          defaultView: 'timeLine3Months',
          views: {
            timeLine3Months: {
              type: 'timeline',
              duration: { months: 3 }
            }
          },
          viewRender: this.viewRender,
          resources,
          events,
          resourceAreaWidth: 200,
          resourceLabelText:  'Profili',
          eventRender: this.eventRender,
          resourceRender: this.resourceRender
        });
      },
```

there's nothing special in there. the result is this:

[image: preview problem]

As you could see, all the events have a 2px width. The problem is fixed when I try to resize the resource labels. Anyone had the same problem? Thank you

Comment: I would recommend using Vue calendar component instead of jQuery one. Including jQuery inside Vue project is not advisable.

Comment: I cannot agree with you more, but I didn't choose to use Jquery, since it was a directive from the top!

Comment: any particular reason why you destroy and then immediately re-create the calendar? There's very rarely a reason for that. Apart from that, visual issues like the one you've shown are almost always due to some custom CSS clashing with the fullCalendar CSS